# I want to assign my custom setting to my custom profile users?

Tags: apex, customsetting

I have my custom setting object Setting  type  **Hierarchy** and  visibility  **Public**.  with 1 text type field and I want to give access to my custom profiles users. U have assigned the permission to my custom profile but users still not getting the access of the  custom setting? How can i assign the proper permission to the user ?

Comment: What type of license is your custom profile for?

Comment: Salesforce license

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's the answer you're looking for... https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=cs_about.htm

> To manage, create, edit, and delete custom settings you need: “Customize Application”

If this permission is too powerful you'll have to expose the setting to them - for example as a Visualforce page. There are lots of hierarchy CS examples:

- http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003862
- http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm
- http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/04/how-to-display-custom-setting-data.html (that's a list setting though I think)
- I've recently provided one sample in [How to retain a selected value of a drop down pick list in home page narrow component after page refresh?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22981/how-to-retain-a-selected-value-of-a-drop-down-pick-list-in-home-page-narrow-comp)

Comment: Hi eyes scream, I am actually using the example you provided me earlier to retain the custom setting. It works perfect in my developing org. However, when I created a managed package with this setting, my subscriber org doesn't seems to get access to this setting for any user other than Administrator.
Can you help me know what am I missing here? Is there any other configuration I need to do, so that when someone install the app, they should be able to manage this setting and add users/profiles to get access to this setting?

Comment: I didn't notice you're the same asker, sorry :D Hm... Only sysadmins will be able to modify that setting in the Setup. But it should just work for all regular users via that page as long as they have permissions to use that page. Is the component added to their home page? And is the page listed in the Profiles?

Comment: yes i have assign page to the user profile and   the it is the component. user view the page but selected filed not work for the other user except admin ..!

Comment: and if you go to the setup and click "manage" on the setting - how many entries does it have? The organisation level? Profile level? Or some records per user? What's the API version of the controller? http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_HierarchyCustomSetting_getInstance.htm says it behaves differently below v. 21. And you're sure it's a hierarchy setting and not list? really weird...

Comment: i set the profile level and user level . My Controller  API Version is 28.0  and im sure i'm using  **hierarchy setting** with visibility Public not  using list .

Comment: i'm getting this error when update the value on custom profile
system.security.NoAccessException: Update access denied for Country__c

Comment: Really running out of ideas here. Maybe try with controller marked as `without sharing`? Are you showing an `<apex:inputField>`? What if you'd flip it to manually made `<apex:selectList>`?

Comment: No im using with sharing, public  with sharing  Class CountryPicker{ .... } and manually made <apex:selectList>

Comment: Try `without` so it should be running on administrator's access rights.

Comment: yes it is running on administrator's access but not run on any other custom profile..! I try without but give the same exception

Answer (score 0):

I answered it on your other retain value question. 
If you have assigned a user to a setting, you should be able to have access to it via APEX.
Try to user the fully qualified variable name in your code with namespace that should resolve any access issue.